# Can't get icon to show in custom button control

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I'm developing a WPF app which contains many buttons which need to contain some text and possibly an icon. I want these buttons to have a consistent style but with the possibility to change the text and/or icon. I'm using `Mahapps.Metro` for styling as well as the `Mahapps.Metro.IconPacks` library for the icon. Here is what I have been duplicating across the app for each button:

```
<Button Padding="15 5" 
    Margin="5 5 30 5"
    Command="{Binding AcceptCommand}" 
    FontSize="14"
    Style="{StaticResource CustomAccentedSquareButtonStyle}"
    Grid.Column="2">
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="Test"
               Margin="0 0 5 0"
               x:Name="TestTextBlock"/>
    <Rectangle Width="12" Height="12" 
               Fill="{Binding ElementName=TestTextBlock, Path=Foreground}">
        <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
            <VisualBrush Visual="{StaticResource appbar_check}" Stretch="Fill" />
        </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
    </Rectangle>
</StackPanel>
```

and the `CustomAccentedSquareButtonStyle`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource AccentedSquareButtonStyle}"
       x:Key="CustomAccentedSquareButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush2}"/>
    <Setter Property="controls:ControlsHelper.ContentCharacterCasing" Value="Normal"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush3}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

So instead of duplicating the same code for the `Button` everywhere, I decided to try and make a custom button with some Dependency Properties:

```
public class CustomButton : Button
{

    public Canvas Icon
    {
        get { return (Canvas)GetValue(IconProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Icon", typeof(Canvas), typeof(CustomButton), new PropertyMetadata(defaultValue: null));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(CustomButton), new PropertyMetadata(defaultValue: null));


    public int IconWidth
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(IconWidthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconWidthProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconWidthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IconWidth", typeof(int), typeof(CustomButton), new PropertyMetadata(0));

    public int IconHeight
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(IconHeightProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconHeightProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconHeightProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IconHeight", typeof(int), typeof(CustomButton), new PropertyMetadata(0));

}
```

and the Style for my custom `Button`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type customControls:CustomButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource CustomAccentedSquareButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type customControls:CustomButton}">
                <customControls:CustomButton Style="{StaticResource CustomAccentedSquareButtonStyle}"
                                                  Padding="15 5">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"
                                   Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                        <Rectangle Width="{TemplateBinding IconWidth}" 
                                   Height="{TemplateBinding IconHeight}" 
                                   Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}">
                            <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                <VisualBrush Visual="{TemplateBinding Icon}" 
                                             Stretch="Fill" />
                            </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </StackPanel>
                </customControls:CustomButton>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

...and then finally using the button in xaml:

```
<customControls:CustomButton Command="{Binding TestCommand}"
                              Text="Test" 
                              Icon="{StaticResource appbar_people}"
                              IconWidth="15"
                              IconHeight="15"
                              Grid.Column="1"/>
```

**Problem:** The icon isn't displaying. The text is displaying so setting the dependency property `Text` and using it in my `ControlTemplate` for the button style is obviously working. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Is the type of the `appbar_people` resource really a Canvas? It looks quite odd to use Canvas as the type of an Icon property.

Comment: @Clemens The icons themselves are all stored in an `Icons.xaml` file which was download with the `Mahapps.Metro.IconPacks` Nuget. Each icon is a `Canvas` with a `Path` element inside. So to me it seemed like the right type to choose for the Icon dp.

Comment: And you're sure you always want to use them only for an OpacityMask?

Comment: @Clemens I'm not sure what you mean? Could you suggest how you would attempt to solve my problem i.e. if you had my requirements what would you do?

Comment: I don't know what your requirements are. Currently you are using the Canvas icon as the Visual of a VisualBrush that is used as OpacityMask of a Rectangle. If you don't know *why* you are doing that, I have no idea how to help.

Comment: @Clemens I'm doing that because of the Mahapps documentation... just like a lot of things in software, we dont always know why we do things because we dont have to as long as it works. I've explained my requirements in the first paragraph - create a custom button with text and an icon property.

Comment: Or you could just use an image control and a textblock and put it inside a button and save yourself tons of problems... *shrug*  This code seems overcomplicated to me.  Just because someone CAN do something, doesn't mean you NEED to either...  Keep it simple...